# How to do index to index value comparison in Unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, text-processing

I have a scenario where i did **array_1 [index]** value check with **array_2 [index]** value.

My below code is working like a charm, but is there any different approach to achieve the same?

I'm looking for a unique way of handling 2 array list values and compare,
with few lines of code.

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash

array_1=(4 4 3)
array_2=(4 1 3)

i=''
j=''

count=0
for i in "${array_1[@]}"
do 
 i="cmd ${array_1[$count]}"
 j="cmd ${array_2[$count]}"
   
     if [ "$i" -eq "$j" ]
     then
           echo "${array_1[$count]} match with ${array_2[$count]}"
           count=$(( count + 1 ))        
     else 
           echo "${array_1[$count]} does not match with ${array_2[$count]}"
           exit 1
     fi 
      
done
```

Note: Code is checked with [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) , no error found.

If two arrays have different values, below is the output:

```
array_1=(4 4 3)
array_2=(4 1 3)
```

Output:

```
4 match with 4
4 does not match with 1
```

If two arrays have the same values, below is the output:

```
array_1=(4 4 3)
array_2=(4 4 3)
```

Output:

```
4 match with 4
4 match with 4
3 match with 3
```

Comment: You should tag your questions with the shell you're actually using rather than just `shell` as different shells have very different ways of doing things.

Comment: why do you have `i="cmd ${array_1[$count]}"` instead of `i="${array_1[$count]}"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You added `awk` to your question.

With `awk` you could do:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{x[FNR]=$1; next}
     x[FNR]==$1{print x[FNR] " match with " $1; next}
     {print x[FNR] " does not match with " $1}
     ' <(printf "%s\n" "${array_1[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${array_2[@]}")
```

Or with `paste` and `awk` you can do:

```
paste <(printf "%s\n" "${array_1[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${array_2[@]}") | awk '
$1==$2{print $1 " match with " $2; next}
{print $1 " does not match with " $2}'
```

Either prints (with the two arrays in your example):

```
4 match with 4
4 does not match with 1
3 match with 3
```

If you want to exit after the first no match, just add `exit` after the `print`:

```
awk 'FNR==NR{x[FNR]=$1; next}
     x[FNR]==$1{print x[FNR] " match with " $1; next}
     {print x[FNR] " does not match with " $1; exit 1}
     ' <(printf "%s\n" "${array_1[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${array_2[@]}")
```

**Explanations**

The construct of `printf "%s\n" "${array_1[@]}"` creates the output of `array_1` as a string separated by `\n`:

```
printf "%s\n" "${array_1[@]}"
4
4
3
```

The construct of:

```
cmdX <(cmdY)
```

Does the following:

1. Creates an anonymous file-like fifo in the shell from the stdout of `cmdY` and
2. Feeds a file name to that file-like output into `cmdX` as an argument to then be read as file.

`paste` takes two file-like inputs and creates a two column single output:

```
paste <(printf "%s\n" "${array_1[@]}") <(printf "%s\n" "${array_2[@]}") 
4   4
4   1
3   3
```

Once you have the arrays side by side or as if two files then comparing the two with `awk` `diff` `comm` `perl` or `ruby` is trivial.

Answer (score 2):

As with your other recent shell questions you shouldn't be doing this in shell at all but since you seem focused on doing so, here's how to do what you're doing briefly (minus the exact output formatting):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

array_1=(4 4 3)
array_2=(4 1 3)

diff -y <(printf '%s\n' "${array_1[@]}") <(printf '%s\n' "${array_2[@]}")
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
4                                                               4
4                                                             | 1
3                                                               3
```

and here's how to write the code in your question in shell (your existing code will fail if your arrays aren't the same size):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

array_1=(4 4 3)
array_2=(4 1 3)

size1=${#array_1[@]}
size2=${#array_2[@]}
if (( size1 > size2 )); then
    maxSize=$size1
else
    maxSize=$size2
fi

for (( i=0; i<maxSize; i++ )); do

     val1=${array_1[i]}
     val2=${array_2[i]}

     if [ "$val1" -eq "$val2" ]
     then
           echo "${array_1[$i]} match with ${array_2[$i]}"
     else
           echo "${array_1[$i]} does not match with ${array_2[$i]}"
           exit 1
     fi

done
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
4 match with 4
4 does not match with 1
```

but the better way to do it, assuming you do need to start off with 2 shell arrays for some reason, would be:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

array_1=(4 4 3)
array_2=(4 1 3)

awk -v string_1="${array_1[*]}" -v string_2="${array_2[*]}" '
    BEGIN {
        size1 = split(string_1,array_1)
        size2 = split(string_2,array_2)

        maxSize = (size1 > size2 ? size1 : size2)

        for (i=1; i<=maxSize; i++) {
            val1 = array_1[i]
            val2 = array_2[i]

            if ( val1 == val2 ) {
                printf "%s match with %s\n", array_1[i], array_2[i]
            }
            else {
                printf "%s does not match with %s\n", array_1[i], array_2[i]
                exit 1
            }
        }
    }
'
```

```
$ ./tst.sh
4 match with 4
4 does not match with 1
```